# Trying to add a value to my previous value I generated

Tags: javascript, blackjack

I'm trying to create a blackjack game, and I created an object of a deck where every time I press the button, it will generate another random card from the deck. My goal is to make the value of the number I generated add up until the user playing decides to stop and give him the total in the end.

this is the code i came up with for now:

```
    var deck = {
    2: [2,2,2,2],
    3: [3,3,3,3],
    4: [4,4,4,4],
    5: [5,5,5,5],
    6: [6,6,6,6],
    7: [7,7,7,7],
    8: [8,8,8,8],
    9: [9,9,9,9],
    10: [10,10,10,10],
    J: [11,11,11,11],
    Q: [12,12,12,12],
    K: [13,13,13,13]
}

$("button").on('click', function(){
var randomkey = deck[Object.keys(deck)[Math.floor(Math.random()*Object.keys(deck).length)]];
var random = randomkey[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomkey.length)];
$('h1').text(random)
})
```

How do I save the previous value so I can add them up in the end together?

Answer (score 0):

You can just save the total of the cards drawn to a separate variable and keep incrementing that whenever you draw a new card

```
let total = 0

// After each card drawn add
total += random
```